# Copying large files using Remote Desktop

Tags: copy, rdp

I have a 4 GB text file, compressed to 1.4 GB zip file. I need to copy it over to a Windows secure server using RDP. I am able to copy small files but not this file. It takes 15 mins and then shows an error. Any tips?

Comment: Besides splitting it into smaller files and using a better compression methods?

Comment: Any recommended open source file splitter? Quite restricted options at work due to security.

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2258090/copying-files-larger-than-2-gb-over-a-remote-desktop-services-or-termi) that "Copying files larger than 2 GB using Clipboard Redirection is not supported." It seems to be unreliable for files approaching this limit.

Answer (score 51):

You can try to copy it by using Drive Redirection. Here's a [tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/18/remote-desktop-file-copy.aspx/).

BTW, RDP cannot copy files larger than 2GB by using clipboard as said in [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2258090/en-us)

Comment: And five years later it's still broken. The failure mode is unfriendly, too. It's completely silent while copying. There's no indication that it has failed, nor even an indication of whether it's still working or finished. The only indication is that the destination file stops growing. The limit is 2GB - 1 = 0x7FFFFFFF. Obviously some lazy programmer used a 32-bit signed integer counter. Oops. Maybe that's why the new Win10 Remote Desktop App doesn't seem to support copy/paste at all: they fixed the Remote Desktop Connection file copy/paste bug by de-supporting the feature.

Comment: And in 2022, there is still a limit...

Answer (score 26):

window rdp clipboard has limit of about 2GB if you want to copy paste more than 2 gb file then you can try any of these options.

1. split file into parts like 1 gb each part with help of winrar or any other software
2. Use any FTP software
3. map local pc drive for remote desktop session(for move or copy data)
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out that in mRemote you can scroll down in the config and enable redirect on your disk drives to share your drives with the remote computer, allowing you to copy large files.

Comment: Mapping a local drive still seems to error out with files over 2gb. I use both steps 1 and 2 with success.

Answer (score 24):

File size doesn't matter - I copied folders through Remote Desktop connection with 30GB and more. While doing this I received **"Unspecified error"**. The Problem is that you **aren't** allowed to use the clipboard again while you are copying. Doesn't matter if you use the clipboard for the same machine or from the remote machine. To summarize don't use Ctrl+C.

The madness is the error is delayed so you don't recognize quickly that those things relate.

Comment: Well done, I can confirm that this is the solution to my problems on Windows 10 with files of any size, but it's more noticeable with large files. I frequently copy files from RDP sessions and often get Unspecified Error while I let the RDP session run in the background. Any use of the clipboard causes the file copying procedure to fail. I would suggest an edit to the above in English: "Don't use Ctrl-C" (instead of German STRG-C). I will make the change now.

Comment: Glad i could help and thanks for the edit and further for the confirmation that the solution works. Feel free for further edits.

Comment: This is one of the gotcha. Also if you're using vmware or other virtual machine, using ctrl+c inside guest will result in the same symptom. So don't even use ctrl+c in guest.

Comment: Wow. This is absolutely wild.

Comment: This did the trick in case of "Unspecified error"!

Comment: For me, large file copies fail instantly, but I surmise that in your case, the file copy begins OK and runs until the clipboard gets clobbered?

Comment: @mwfearnley Yes it starts "normal" but as soon as I copy something else it stops instantly.

Answer (score 2):

1. format usb drive as ntfs
2. connect drive as local resource in remote desktop
3. `NET USE X: \\TSCLIENT\F`
4. `robocopy c:\source x:\`
5. `net use X: /delete`

Answer (score 2):

If you are administrator, you can copy the files of any size over the network using [Administrative Shares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) assuming that it is not purposefully disabled.

Enter the following url on your File Explorer and you will see all the files and folders on your C drive of that computer with read and write access:

```
\\computername\c$
```

Answer (score -1):

right-click zip-file >> Properties >> Advanced >> Encrypt contents

open your one-drive or googledrive (if the secure server allows you) and park the encrypted file on there.

(you might have to one-drive space by signing up to a months 365)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-your-onedrive-storage-and-limits-989fce19-ade6-4e2f-81fb-941eabefee28

I guess it would might be possible to use google datastore or something cloudy.